# Building multi-tenant and reactive application using spring 5 and mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, multi-tenant

I want to build a multi-tenant and reactive application using Spring 5, spring-boot 2, project reactor and MongoDB.

To separate persistent data for each tenant and its users, I would like that each tenant has its own mongo database. I don’t want to add a “tenantId” field in each persisted document. (I can change my mind if you have another and better idea).

I already managed to do this thing thanks to spring security, ThreadLocal and a “MultiTenantMongoDbFactory” class. You can have a look at this resource that helped me: https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

This is great, but this can’t work with reactive application. Do you have any idea how can I easily implement a solution like this one in a Spring reactive application?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You also might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: I think this has the potential to become an on-topic question, but it's too broad as-is. In particular, you need to show *in the question* what approach you took to make it work and what the difference is with the reactive APIs that you're needing help with.